# DBConcurrencyException. Sqlite TableAdapter using UpdateCommand instead of InsertCommand

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, sqlite, dataset

```
        Dim newRow As wilsysFixedDataSet.FormulaRow =
            blend.formulaDataSet.Formula.NewFormulaRow
```

*Severals lines later after setting all the properties of the new row....*

```
        Console.WriteLine("Current Row State Before Added: {0}", newRow.RowState)

        blend.formulaDataSet.Formula.AddFormulaRow(newRow)

        Console.WriteLine("Current Row State After Added: {0}", newRow.RowState)

        Console.WriteLine(blend.formulaDataSet.Formula.Contains(newRow))

        blend.formulaTableAdapter.Update(blend.formulaDataSet.Formula)
```

I am having an issue when trying to use a Form to create a new Formula record, add that row to the FormulaDataTable, then Call the FormulaDataSetTableAdapter.update() method with the FormulaDataTable as a parameter. I ensured the id property of the row doesnt already exist, and all the other necessary properties are set, and the row doesnt already exist in the dataTable. 
For some STRANGE reason, the TableAdapter is choosing to call the UPDATECOMMAND as you can see in the stack trace below, when it should be inserting. 
Why is this and what can i do to have it call the appropriate method with the new row.

Here I am printing to the console:
 - newRow.RowState before adding newRow to the  DataTable 
 - newRow.RowState after adding newRow to the DataTable
 - DataTable.Contains(newRow)
 - List item

```
Current Row State Before Added: Detached
Current Row State After Added: Added
True
```

Below I am receiving the following StackTrace when executing the 
DataSetTableAdapter.update(FormulaDataTable):

```
System.Data.DBConcurrencyException: Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable dataTable)
   at RepackWPF.wilsysFixedDataSetTableAdapters.FormulaTableAdapter.Update(FormulaDataTable dataTable)
   at RepackWPF.NewFormDialog.NewFormula()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i was able to solve this issue by "flushing" the changes to records on the FormulaDataSet(the main dataset holding the tableadapters) by calling the

```
FormulaDataSet.AcceptChanges()
```

method. I had to call this before each of the update calls on FormulaDataSet.
This set the RowState from Modified to Unchanged, and allowed the transaction to go through.